# Does FilterOutpuStream perform write normally or not?

Tags: java, filter, stream, output, java-io

Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) says:

> write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
>
> Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off
> to this output stream. The write method of FilterOutputStream calls
> the write method of one argument on each byte to output.
>
> Note that this method **does not call** the write method of its underlying
> **input** stream *with the same arguments*. Subclasses of FilterOutputStream
> should provide a more efficient implementation of this method.

I have two questions:

1. On [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/filteroutputstream_write_byte.htm) page I found code that uses `FilterOutputStream` for decoration of `FileOutputStream`, and writes normal output to file. Why is `FilterOutputStream` calling `write()` method of underlying stream on each byte, when it's able to call same overload on underlying stream and make operation faster?
2. Why is underlying stream **input** stream?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I believe the point is that if you want a very *simple* filter, you can just override the `write(int)` method, and know that everything will pass through that. It will be inefficient, but work. So if you wanted a stream which filtered out every even byte, you could do that easily:

   ```
   public class OddByteOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream
   {
       public OddByteOutputStream(OutputStream output)
       {
           super(output);
       }

       @Override
       public void write(int b)
       {
           if ((b & 1) == 1)
           {
               out.write(b);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   An alternative approach would have been to make `write(byte[])` delegate, but make `write(int)` and `write(byte[], int, int)` abstract, to *force* subclasses to work out how to handle the calls reasonably efficiently.
2. This is just a typo, I suspect.

Comment: Thanks. One more optional question: do I have to call `super()` version in own overrides of this method?

Comment: @user35443: Of `write(byte[], int, int)`? Absolutely not - doing so would lead to duplicate data, assuming you were *also* then handling the data yourself in your override.